# Computing stats with data ignore values - ENVI classic

Tags: landsat, statistics, envi, landsat-8

I'm using ENVI classic (5.4.1) and trying to compute basic statistics from a Landsat-8 scene. When I mask out certain pixels (water set to 'No Data', for instance) the built-in ENVI statistics still takes the water pixels into account and treats them as zeros.

Is there a way to compute statistics in ENVI while truly ignoring the data ignore values?